# Wrong context when calling method

Tags: c++, inheritance

How can I achieve that CoroutineManager::Routine() calls Operator::Worker() ?
Worker() must be called by Routine() in this test scenario.
So the question is whether how C++ handle the context. The Routine() method must not implemented by the Operator class itself.

```
template <class T>
class CoroutineManager {
  private:
    T var;
    int _a, _b;
  public:
    CoroutineManager(int a, int b);
    T Worker();
    void Routine();
};

template <class T>
CoroutineManager<T>::CoroutineManager(int a, int b) {
    this->_a = a;
    this->_b = b;
}

template <class T>
T CoroutineManager<T>::Worker() {
    std::cout << "wrong method" << std::endl;
    return var;
}

template <class T>
void CoroutineManager<T>::Routine() {
    std::cout << this->Worker() << std::endl;
}

class Operator : public CoroutineManager<double> {
    using CoroutineManager::CoroutineManager;
public:
    Operator(int a, int b) : CoroutineManager(a,b) {};
    virtual double Worker();
};

double Operator::Worker() {
    return 3.141;
}

// MARK: -

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
   
    Operator *op = new Operator(3,4);

    op->Routine();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if `T` is not `double`?

Comment: You need to make `Routine` virtual in `CoroutineManager` to get polymorphism.  That said, inheritance implies an is-a relationship and it seems weird to me that you have `Operator` is a `CoroutineManager`

Comment: @NathanOliver virtual or CRTP, but yes, I agree on the rest of your comment.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the code to fulfill my requirements, but maybe there are exists more straight forward solutions(?). It's only about `Worker` and `Worker2`, two different methods in two objects which can be called by the derived `Routine` method without the boundaries of inheritance context:

```
// MARK: -

template <typename T, typename V>
class CoroutineManager {
  private:
    V _a, _b;
    V (T::*workerPtr)();
    T *cm;
  public:
    CoroutineManager(V a, V b) {
        this->_a = a;
        this->_b = b;
    }
    void Routine() {
        std::cout << (*cm.*workerPtr)() << std::endl;
    }
    void SetWorker(T *cm, V (T::*ptr)()) {
        this->workerPtr = ptr;
        this->cm = cm;
    }
    V getA() {
        return this->_a;
    }
    V getB() {
        return this->_b;
    }
};


// MARK: -

class Operator : public CoroutineManager<Operator,int> {

private:
    int xx;
public:
    Operator(int a, int b) : CoroutineManager(a,b) {
        this->xx = a*2 + b*2;
    };
    int Worker();
};

int Operator::Worker() {
    return getA() * getB() + this->xx;
}

// MARK: -

class Operator2 : public CoroutineManager<Operator2,double> {

public:
    Operator2(double a, double b) : CoroutineManager(a,b) {};
    double Worker2();
};

double Operator2::Worker2() {
    return getA() + getB();
}



// MARK: -

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
   
    Operator *op = new Operator(4,4);
    int (Operator::*workerPtr)() = &Operator::Worker;
    op->SetWorker(op, workerPtr);
    op->Routine();
   
    Operator2 *op2 = new Operator2(3.14,2.78);
    double (Operator2::*workerPtr2)() = &Operator2::Worker2;
    op2->SetWorker(op2, workerPtr2);
    op2->Routine();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
32
5.92
Program ended with exit code: 0
```